# Symfony 3 Sonata Admin create admin using annotation

Tags: php, symfony, admin, sonata

I try to create a sonata admin using only annotation from JMSDiExtraBundle.

Admin:

```
/**
 * @DI\Service("sonata.admin.company")
 * @DI\Tag("sonata.admin", attributes = {
 *     "manager_type" = "orm",
 *     "label"="Category",
 *     "group"="Orders"
 *      })
 */
class CompanyAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "code" = @DI\Inject("%admin__company__class%"),
     *     "class" = @DI\Inject("%admin__company__code%"),
     *     "baseControllerName" = @DI\Inject("%admin__company__base_controller_name%")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
    }
}
```

And file with parameters:

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
    admin__company__class: AppBundle\Entity\Company
    admin__company__base_controller_name: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
    admin__company__code: admin.company
```

When i register admin in yml it work, but using annotation no.

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/configuration) states:

> By default, you can only use the provided annotations on your non-service controllers; no other directories are scanned.
>
> However, if you also would like to use annotations to configure your regular services, you can configure more locations as demonstrated below.
>
> If you would like to configure services in a bundle of yours via annotations, or have some services outside of any bundles structure such as in your src/ directory, you can make use of the following configuration options, so that the bundle will pick them up, and add them to your dependency injection container:

```
jms_di_extra:
    locations:
        all_bundles: false
        bundles: [FooBundle, AcmeBlogBundle]
        directories: ["%kernel.root_dir%/../src"]
```

Comment: @TomaszFurca, if this answered your question, please mark the answer!